# Unclear downvote reasons

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I would like to understand why  [Tips and advice for getting consistent pay raises and in general advancing one's career in corporate bureaucracies](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17764/2651) is being downvoted because none of the comments actually point to reasons why. I've tried to clarify the question to the point where I think it is specific enough in scope to solicit answers but so far I'm just getting a lot of comments directed personally to me instead of addressing the question.

I have given the background for the question. I have provided a specific insight on my end that in theory should improve my chances of success in advancing my career and I've closed the question by asking for more examples of such actionable insights. I would like to know what else is there to do?

Comment: @Kate, fyi posting a raw link like `http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17764/2651` will automatically resolve as the question title, so no need to do fancy `[]()` markup for question titles. When I found this out it saved me zillions of hours, so I figure I'd share (note: it doesn't work on deleted questions, though does work cross-site on the SE network)

Comment: I know, I was editing the link from "this question" which is what was there before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the question was downvoted. Explanations for downvotes aren't required and are seldom offered. But just because a question is downvoted, that doesn't mean you won't get a helpful answer.

It's possible that some feel that your question is too specific, and not applicable to a wide enough workplace.stackexchange audience, or is otherwise "not useful".

It appears that your question currently has 2 Close votes due to:
"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: The downvote is not what is bothering me. If the question is unclear then the comments should address that aspect but all comments are clearly directed at me personally instead of what is written in the question itself so I'm a little confused as to why. Lack of focus might be it but I think I have been pretty clear in asking about actionable strategies in corporate settings for career advancement. I don't know how much clearer I can be. Obviously more because of all the confusion in the comments.

Comment: As for the applicability. I'm not sure what's more applicable than best practices for advancing one's career in corporate settings. Unless everyone on this stackexchange is a freelancer or working on a startup my question should have wide applicability.

Comment: I always say - there are no best practices. There are practices that sometimes work well, in some contexts. "Corporate settings" encompass an extremely wide variety of situations, and useful responses. I think you are looking for something that isn't there.

Comment: Sure. In that case the question should indeed be closed.

Answer (score 5):

> Note: As Joe's answer points out, downvotes are anonymous and are not required to be explained. There are a zillion [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta Stack Overflow asking for people to be forced to explain themselves, but they are constantly declined. As a result, the below is speculation on my part.

Questions that ask for 'Tips or Advice' are usually downvoted because they are viewed as off-topic and low quality for the following reasons:

1. [Polling is a bad fit for the SE format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75035/209637)
2. [Recommendations are a bad fit for the SE format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

For your question in specific, it seems like you've already solved your own problem (you realize that the issue is that you have to communicate your value better to your bosses), and you are just asking for any other advice. As explained in the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), questions should be *"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"*, so when it seems like you've already solved the problem, it makes the question hard to answer.